# Passing five strings to a method in objective-c xcode

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I was just mulling over a programming design question:

Say, am passing 5 strings to a method from one class to another. They are details like, say:
Host name
Host domain
User subdomain
User name
Password

Which is better?
1. Passing them as an array of NSString objects
or
2. Redefine the called method to accept 5 different NSString parameters?

Which is a more efficient way to do it?

Comment: You could do it like `- (void)myMethod:(NSString*)str1, ...;` Which will accept an unknown amount of parameters so you could then do `[self myMethod:hostName, user, subdomain];` or `[self myMethod:hostName, user];` you can pass however many you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You missed a third way of doing it - passing a custom object that encloses the five fields:

```
@interface HostDef // Pick a good name that fits well the purpose of your method.
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) NSString* hostName;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) NSString* hostDomain;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) NSString* userSubdomain;
...
@end
```

This is the most descriptive and extensible way of doing it: in case you need to extend the list of items passed in, you change the `HostDef`, while the signature of your method stays in place.

If the number of parameters is likely to remain five for a foreseeable future, a method with five separate arguments is equally as good. Specifically, if the number of arguments corresponds to something fundamental in the world or in the algorithm that is not going to change, a method with individual arguments is a good choice. For example, if your method takes a left subtree and a right subtree of a binary tree as its inputs, having two arguments is appropriate, because a binary tree cannot get more or fewer arguments without becoming something other than a binary tree.

Passing a plain array of unnamed objects is the least readable choice, which is also the hardest to maintain. Unless all objects have the same "meaning" to the program, they should not be put into the same array. For example, putting a host domain and user subdomain into the same array is a quick way to mislead the readers of your program, substantially complicating the maintenance.

Comment: More to add - it's a good pattern to extract method parameters to a method object. Totally agree with this answer, expect I would pick more description name here - HostParameters or UserLogin.

Comment: @Vladimir I agree. I do not know enough about OP's method to name the class appropriately, so I added a comment asking the OP to rename the parameters class. Thanks!

Comment: Consider using '@property (nonatomic, copy) ...' for your NSString parameters (so you know any parameter set with a mutable instance won't result in changes behind your back.

Comment: @Wain Although I generally do prefer `(nonatomic, copy)` on my `NSString` properties, "transient" objects like this one are a notable exception from this rule. It is very likely that the strings contained in this "method parameter object" will be moved to their permanent place among the properties of a real, "non-transient", object. That's where the copying should take place. Copying strings into the parameters object is OK, but it may lead to some unnecessary double-copying.

Comment: Not sure I fully agree. I don't think there should be a double copy as immutable items should just return, not copy. But anyway, it's a protection against inadvertent modification (you don't know how long the object is going to exist and therefore what might happen before it gets used).

Comment: You can also go with a `NSDictionary` if you don't want to create a custom class.

Comment: Thank you for all your replies! It helped!